# How do I add a vertical gutter between rows like bootstrap adds between columns?

Tags: css

**tl;dr: adding vertical gutters to my grid system like bootstrap's horizontal gutters (negative margins and positive padding) breaks clearfix.**

For fun I'm making a grid system like bootstrap's. I've added negative margins to the rows and positive padding to the columns:

```
.row {
    margin: -15px 0;
    display: block;
}

.row > * {
    padding: 15px 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.row > *:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.row .col-1 { width: 8.333%; }
.row .col-2 { width: 16.666%; }
.row .col-3 { width: 25%; }
// ...
```

This gives me horizontal gutters like Bootstrap 3's grid system. It even allows me to nest rows and columns properly:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for>Label</label>
                <input type="text" class="input error" value="Error" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="input warning" value="Warning" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So next is a vertical gutter, because it's always irked me that with bootstrap's grid system rows stack without spacing. I *could* add a margin-bottom to each row, but that doesn't allow me to nest rows and columns. So, I added negative margin and positive padding:

```
.row {
    margin: -15px -15px; // kept separate in case I want the vertical gutter to be differently sized than the horizontal gutter
    display: block;
}

.row > * {
    padding: 15px -15px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

And this adds a sweet vertical gutter and allows me to nest rows and even use more than 12 column units (aka allows columns to wrap while still keeping the gutter.) It actually works pretty well, provided the heights are the same: https://jsfiddle.net/8auw0s6k/

BUT

This breaks as soon as any column is higher than another, likely because the clearfix is not working with a negative margin. And many columns will have different heights, obviously: https://jsfiddle.net/eajpzeeh/1/

Is there a better way to have vertical gutters while allowing nesting? Or is there a way to make the clearfix work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are making grid system like bootstrap but you forgot one thing bootstrap uses that is `clearfix` you need to use it in you layout also.

> If you are using float then you need to clear that float also by using clear in your row

```
.row { margin: -0.5rem -0.5rem; display: block; clear: both; }
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/eajpzeeh/6/

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eajpzeeh/3/)**

Simply adding `clear: both` on class `.row` should be enough to stop any float displacement.